# PHPExcel get column name relative to given column

Tags: php, phpexcel

Using PHPExcel, is it possible to get the name of a column located X number of columns to the left or right?

Example, given column BZ, I'd like to return column name CB or BX. (2 to the right or left)

Thanks

Comment: One quick hack would be to calculate the 'value' of `CB` as a number, add 2 and then lookup that value. You'd have an array `$lettervalues {0 => null, 1 => 'A', ... 'Z' => 26}` and do some math in PHP.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are functions already built into PHPExcel to help you do this

```
$adjustment = -2;
$currentColumn = 'BZ';

$columnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($currentColumn);
$adjustedColumnIndex = $columnIndex + $adjustment;
$adjustedColumn = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($adjustedColumnIndex - 1);
```

Note the (historic) discrepancy that columnIndexFromString() will return a 1 for column A, but that stringFromColumnIndex expects a 0 to correspond to column A

Comment: This is just what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: PHPExcel has now been superceded by PhpSpreadsheet and `stringFromColumnIndex` was moved to a new class called `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate` See docs [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/)